# MIPS not running (code dropped off bottom, infinite loop?)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have a project that I'm struggling with and I can't figure out the error in my code (I'm fairly new to MIPS btw). Given a function, F = (A*B) xor (C*D), I have to compute the full truth-table as a and count the number of one values (minterms) in standard truth table for F. The output should be displayed on the display console. Here is my code:

```
.data
space: .asciiz " "
str: .asciiz "The number of minterms in F is: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
.text

li $t0, 0       #A = 0
li $t1, 0       #B = 0
li $t2, 0       #C = 0
li $t3, 0       #D = 0
li $t4, 0       #counter = 0

loop:
and $t5, $t0, $t1   #$t5 = A and B
and $t6, $t2, $t3   #$t6 = B and C
xor $t5, $t5, $t6   #$t5 = (A and B) xor (B and C)
add $t4, $t4, $t5   #Increment the counter by 1 if F = 1

li $v0, 1

move $a0, $t0       #Print out the values of A, B, C, D, and F
syscall 
move $a1, $t1 
syscall
move $a2, $t2 
syscall
move $a3, $t3 
syscall
la $a0, space 
syscall
move $a1, $t5 
syscall
la $a2, newline
syscall

testA:                  #Test to see if A should be inversed
beq $t1, 1, testCforA           #If B = 1, test to see if C = 1
j testB                 #If B = 0, test to see if B should be inversed
testCforA: beq $t2, 1, testDforA    #If C = 1, test to see if D = 1
j testB                 #If C = 0, test to see if B should be inversed
testDforA: beq $t3, 1, inverseA     #If D = 1, A should be inversed
j testB                 #If D = 0, test to see if B should be inversed

inverseA:               #Inverse bit A
beq $t0, 1, end             #If A = 1, then end the loop because the truth table is completed
li $t0, 1               #If A = 0, then change it to make A = 1

testB:                  #Test to see if B should be inversed
beq $t2, 1, testDforB           #If C = 1, test to see if D = 1
j testC                 #If C = 0, test to see if C should be inversed
testDforB: beq $t3, 1, inverseB     #If D = 1, B should be inversed
j testC                 #If D = 0, test to see if C should be inversed

inverseB:               #Inverse bit B
beq $t1, 1, invB            #If B = 1, then change it to make B = 0
li $t1, 1               #If B = 0, then change it to make B = 1
j testC             
invB: li $t1, 0

testC:                  #Test to see if C should be inversed
beq $t3, 1, inverseC            #If D = 1, C should be inversed
j inverseD              #If D = 0, inverse bit D but DON'T inverse bit C

inverseC:               #Inverse bit C
beq $t2, 1, invC            #If C = 1, then change it to make C = 0
li $t2, 1               #If C = 0, then change it to make C = 1
j inverseD
invC: li $t2, 0

inverseD:               #Inverse bit D
beq $t3, 1, invD            #If D = 1, then change it to make D = 0
li $t3, 1               #If D = 0, then change it to make D = 1
j loop                  #jump back to the beginning of the loop
invD: li $t3, 0
j loop                  #jump back to the beginning of the loop

end:                    #termination of the program
la $a0, str             #Print the number of minterms from the truth table
syscall
move $a0, $t4
syscall
```

The error I keep getting is:

> 00002685009922685009922685009920000268500992268500992268500992000026850099226850099226850099200002685009922685009922685009920000268500992268500992268500992000026850099226850099226850099200002685009922685009922685009920000268500992268500992268500992111126850099226850099226850099211112685009922685009922685009921111268500992268500992268500992111126850099226850099226850099211112685009922685009922685009921111268500992268500992268500992111126850099226850099226850099211112685009922685009922685009922685009946
>   -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --

Any insight would be SOO much appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: What does "dropped off the bottom" mean?  This is not a standard term.

Comment: It seems to be an error message in MIPS: `-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --` I noticed I get this if i do not run ` li $v0, 10  syscall`

Answer (score 1):

The main insight is to use the very good MARS MIPS simulator to single step through the code in order to determine the difference between what you *think* it's doing and what it's *actually* doing.  [This is the home page](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/download.htm).

One obvious thing is that the output `syscall`s can't possibly be right.  To print the first variable, you've loaded it into `a0`, which is correct.  Then to print the second, you load into `a1`!  Can't be right.  Similarly you're trying to print the space and newline with the same `syscall` function number as for printing integers. Strings are 8.  Integers are 1. This value must be in `v0` before the syscall.

Comment: That should say `$v0` not `$v1` @Gene

Comment: @KonradLindenbach  Thanks.  Typing faster than thinking...  Not good.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I believe the most confusing part about this is syscalls. A lot of info I read about them isn't clear.
So I need to load the appropriate value into $v0, then I put whatever I want to output into the a register, right?

Comment: They work like library calls in a high level language.  Here http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html is a nice chart.  Load the `v0` register with the desired function. Set up the arguments in other registers as shown.  Then a `syscall` instruction. Functions that return results will have them also in registers also as shown in the chart.  Beware that return results will change the register values regardless of whether you use them.  You can't count on registers to act like local variables in higher level languages.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to this. I'm working on this program again. I fixed the all the values for $v0 to print the appropriate values. It prints 0000 (the first line of the truth table). However that's all the code does. Meaning there might be a problem in the actual loop, which I've read over multiple times and can't figure out (the loop by the way, is supposed to iterate each line of truth table, so 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, etc.) and after it gets to 1111 it ends. Any help with this?

Comment: @user3517531  Reading it over is nice. But you'll get insight you'll need from stepping through it one line at a time and verifying all registers and memory hold the values you expect and branches occur as you expect.  This is by way of "teach a man to fish".  I could do it, but then you'd never learn to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this solve one day, not specially for your problem, but the sufficient to suppress the "dropped of bottom" error in my code:

put before the beginning of function declarations:

.text

.globl main

just this, worked to me.